# How to get a Javascript variable to the apex controller class

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller, controller-extension

Below is a VF Page I have. I do get the alert message with the URL. I am unable to get theValue variable value in Apex controller. Am I missing something here?

```
<apex:page standardController="Sobject__c" extensions="APage">
<script>
var old = document.referrer;
function setVal(){
document.getElementById("{!$Component.hdnField}").value = document.referrer;
}
alert(old);
</script>
    <script>
        setVal();
    </script>
<apex:form >
<apex:inputHidden id="hdnField" value="{!theValue}" />
</apex:form>
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:detail subject="{! Sobject.id}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class APage {

    public String theValue{get;set;}
    public APage(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

            system.debug('############ the value ################' + theValue);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have submitted the value by the time your constructor is called; the page hasn't loaded yet. However, you should be able to check the referrer from Apex Code this way:

```
public APage(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
  String referrer = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('REFERER');
}
```

Note that this is not a typo; the "referer" header was spelled wrong many years ago, so we're stuck with this for backwards compatibility. Many browsers may choose to not set this header if you're coming from a different domain, so it's really only useful if you're navigating between Visualforce pages.